# Zend Framework 2: Custom config as Zend\Config\Config or plain PHP array, what is the recommended way?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2 I wrote a module with custom configuration options.

The options are obtained using the service locator and are then passed to the object that is being initialized inside a factory.

Since my configuration is in PHP array format, I could just pass the array, or I could first create a new instance of `Zend\Config\Config` and pass this to the new object.

I tried both ways & they both work, but what is the recommended way of doing this inside ZF2 & why? Does it has any advantages to use `Zend\Config\Config`?

Especially since I just noted it's possible to cast the `Config` back to an array using `toArray()` I am curious of possible benefits.

Comment: In might not make a difference in your situation however the object would also be passed by reference and the array by value.

Answer (score 1):

By using the object you would be keeping with the OOP inherent to Zend, plus it has functionality not available to a basic array, and it can be extended to use custom business logic if the need arises.

IE, maybe a condition comes up that will  change one of the configuration options, but the rest are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm developing a project for others, I like to give them a certain level of access to the configuration so that they do not have any reason to delve into the code themselves.  I'll create a table in the database called something like 'settings' or 'config' that the admin can access through a form, and the data populates a php configuration array.  In order to do this, the PHP array format is the way to go.

("a" recommendation, not necessarily "the" recommended way)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the modules just add to the global config, that is accessible via `$serviceManager->get('config')`

This way your config can be cached later on via `config_cache_enabled` in `application.config.php` and users can override config options using their local configurations.

If your's module config isn't related to the global config mechanism it's really up to you on how you store/manage it. Keeping it as an array is simpler, whereas using it as `Zend\Config\Config` lets you use various tools for config (ini writers, database etc).